# Show that a smooth surface is orientable

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function satisfying $\nabla f(\vec{p})\neq0$ for all $\vec{p} \in S$ where $S=\{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3\mid f(\vec{x})=0 \}$. I want to show that $S$ is a smooth orientable surface.

The definition I have for an orientable surface is that a surface $S$ is orientable if for every $\vec{p} \in S$ there exists a smooth choice of standard unit normal.

I know that since $\nabla f(\vec{p}) \neq0$ for all $\vec{p} \in S$ it follows from the Implicit Function Theorem that $S$ is indeed a smooth surface.

How do I check that $S$ is orientable though?

Comment: $\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$

Comment: @JohnMa So since the denominator is non-zero I can always take $\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$ as the standard unit normal?